# Where are the Blender program files in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: add-on, linux, installation

Can anyone tell me where the .blender directory is in Ubuntu 14.04?

I cannot find the .blender directory in my Ubuntu 14.04 system.

I need to know this location so I can put the MakeHuman add on sub-directories there.

Comment: Thanks folks! The Blender program is where you told me it would be. It turns out I totally needed to put the MakeHuman directories into the "scrpts/addons" directory (which had to be created) for Blender to properly install them, as per the instructions at the MakeHuman web site.

Answer (score 10):

By default: see the [doc about directory layout](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing_blender/directorylayout.html#unix-linux-bsd-solaris)

```
# LOCAL
./2.74/

# USER
$HOME/.config/blender/2.74/

# SYSTEM
/usr/share/blender/2.74/
```

Answer (score 4):

[It's usually](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing_blender/directorylayout.html#unix-linux-bsd-solaris) in `~/.config/blender/$version`.

Note that you can also click *Install from file* in the user preferences (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>) to have blender put the scripts where they need to be (It'll even unzip them if they are zipped):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an hidden directory (cause by the dot). A lot of applications create hidden diretories in your home (/home/yourusername/.dontknow)
Look for a directory like this.

I'm not quite sure, I gonna try this later and submut my answer when I'm right

Answer (score 0):

Done with Kubuntu 14.04 Blender 2.77 the MHK2 folder downloaded from 
https://bitbucket.org/ThomasMakeHuman/mhx2-makehuman-exchange/downloads which is a dropbox location you can not get the file unless you make an account with dropbox.

Location for blender to drop the folder to for the addon youll need to use sudo in teminal open terminal and type sudo dolphin terminal will want your password after that dolphin with open go to

Root/usr/share/blender/2.77/scripts/addons

paste the import_runtime_mhx2 folder in that location after that go into blender user preferences addons tab in the search bar at the top left type mhx2 and put a checkmark in the box to enable it then save user settings bottom right restart blender and your done.
I did this post cause i was stumbling around trying to find and answer to this as well and got incomplete answers at best though this article did point out where blender is installed it really didnt help with getting the addon MHX2 installed or say where the addons folder is. 
Main website MHX2 was obtained from is 
https://bitbucket.org/ThomasMakeHuman/mhx2-makehuman-exchange

Comment: I don't understand why you say the first link is a dropbox location, and have to an dropbox account to download. It is hosted on bitbucket and the link you give presents me with the option to download a zip, without being logged in to bitbucket, let alone dropbox which I don't see any connection here.

Comment: Either way that link died since then

Answer (score 0):

For me the addon installation worked with:
https://bitbucket.org/Diffeomorphic/mhx2-makehuman-exchange/src/master/

and blender 2.90 and blender 2.83.4.

But under File->Import there is no *.mhx2 option.

Edit:
It will openable with shortcut n in the toolshelf.